# Return selected tabpage name

Tags: c#, tabpage

How can I get the name of a selected tabpage?

Comment: WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET? Something else?

Answer (score 17):

You can access the name through the tab control which contains the tab page.

```
string name = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

its work

```
TabControl1.TabPages[TabControl1.SelectedIndex].Name.ToString();
```